# Passing an array generated from a separate php file to JPgraph

Tags: php, arrays, post, jpgraph

I have three php arrays named `$smty1;` `$thty2;` `$totaly3` in a file name "objective_matrix.php".

I want to pass these three arrays to the Jpgraph file named graph2.php which is shown below

```
<?php
 require_once('/jpgraph-3.5.0b1/src/jpgraph.php');
 require_once('/jpgraph-3.5.0b1/src/jpgraph_bar.php'); 

//In here I will need the arrays $smty1, $thty2, $totaly3


$graph = new Graph(450,200,'auto');    
$graph->SetScale("textlin");
$graph->SetShadow();
$graph->img->SetMargin(40,30,40,40);
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels($gDateLocale->GetShortMonth());

$graph->yaxis->title->Set('PPM');
$graph->xaxis->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);

$graph->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);

$bplot1 = new BarPlot($smty1);
$bplot2 = new BarPlot($thty2);
$bplot3 = new BarPlot($totaly3);

$bplot1->SetFillColor("orange");
$bplot2->SetFillColor("brown");
$bplot3->SetFillColor("darkgreen");

$bplot1->SetShadow();
$bplot2->SetShadow();
$bplot3->SetShadow();

$bplot1->SetShadow();
$bplot2->SetShadow();
$bplot3->SetShadow();

$gbarplot = new GroupBarPlot(array($bplot1,$bplot2,$bplot3));
$gbarplot->SetWidth(0.6);
$graph->Add($gbarplot);

$graph->Stroke();
?>
```

In "objective_matrix.php" I'm plotting the graph using:
`<img style="position:absolute; top:635px" src="graph2.php" />`

I tried using the URL method to pass these data but I don't know how to pass a variable there. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Normally, if you're passing data to a script via a URL you have to use URL parameters. For example, `<img style="position:absolute; top:635px" src="graph2.php?param1=value1&param2=value2" />`. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: You can pass a variable using this example (if using a form). `$graph1=$_GET['smty1'];` or `$graph1=$_POST['smty1'];`, then use those variables `$smty1` anywhere after that. Add `$thty2` and `$totaly3` accordingly from thereon. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: The thing is I don't know the real values of "value1" or "value2" to assign. Above three arrays will be generated after a vast calculation. I just want to pass the three arrays using URL or any other method.

Comment: Edit your question to include the code you already tried, in order to show us an example.

Comment: Thanks Fred. The code is very large. What I do in there is I save three different types of data belong to months in a particular year in three arrays named "smty1, thty2, totaly3"
And after that I draw a table and in the same page I want to display these arrays graphically using the "graph2.php"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a short solution for your problem Harshanii..
you can save array data ($smty1, $thty2, $totaly3) in temporary database and recall those data in the  graph2.php ..